# JavaScript SyntaxError: missing } after function body

Tags: javascript, regex

So...I'm not proud of myself for posting this but I'm really stuck. I have a form which I want to simply validate in JavaScript and then pass it to a controller. Turns out I get the `Missing }` error and I got no clue why.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form id='contact_form' method='POST' name='contactform'>
<p>First Name: <input name='first_name' type='text' /></p><br/>
<p>Last Name: <input name='last_name' type='text' /></p><br/>
<p>Company: <input name='company' type='text' /></p><br/>
<p>Email Address: <input name='email' type='text' /></p><br/>
<p>Phone: <input name='phone' type='text' /></p><br/>
<p>Address: <input name='address' type='text' /></p><br/>
<p>Message:<textarea name='message'></textarea></p><br/>
<a id='submit'>Submit here</a>
</form>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('#products').on("click", "#submit", function () {

        $('input').removeClass('error');
        $('textarea').removeClass('error');
        var isValid = true;

        // verifica nume si prenume
        var firstNameReg = new RegExp(/^[^\d]{3,}$/);
        if (!firstNameReg.test($('input[name=first_name]').val())) {
            $('input[name=first_name]').addClass('error');
            isValid = false;
        }

        var lastNameReg = new RegExp(/^[^\d]{3,}$/);
        if (!lastNameReg.test($('input[name=last_name]').val())) {
            $('input[name=last_name]').addClass('error');
            isValid = false;
        }

        // verifica telefon
        var telReg = new RegExp(/^[\d]{10}$/);
        if (!telReg.test($('input[name=phone]').val())) {
            $('input[name=phone]').addClass('error');
            isValid = false;
        }

        // verifica email
        var emailReg = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
        if (!emailReg.test($('input[name=email]').val())) {
            $('input[name=email]').addClass('error');
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (isValid) {
            alert("Formularul este completat corect!");
        }
    });
</script>
```

So...if you have any idea please throw me a hint! Thank you!

Comment: In which line do you get this error? Your code looks valid.

Comment: browser only says this : SyntaxError: missing } after function body sk:99:164 but it's in no way at that like

Comment: is there any more code? there doesn't seem to be an error in what you shared

Comment: This is actually it. I added a simple form in a QuickCart CMS. I only added the html itself and the javascript code I posted (entirely) in footer. that's it!

Comment: Are you sure that the browser hasn't cached the script?

Comment: yup, tried cleaning cache, nothing...

Comment: What other libraries are you using (other than jquery)? Try using jquery from [cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/), maybe you have corrupted file somehow.

Comment: I use a plugin that creates a visual effect on image click I think "grid.js" is the name and the jquery from here:    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: You've got two instances of `[\w-\s]`, which is an invalid range.  I don't know if that's the source of your problem, but it's definitely a bad practice.  Any hyphen that's not part of a range expression should be escaped with a backslash or placed at the beginning or end of the list..

Comment: Actually, in JS regex, you can use a hyphen after a shorthand character class and it will be parsed as a literal hyphen. I think there is a more serious issue with `new RegExp(/.../)` since not all browsers support a regex literal inside a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the answer, just and improvement of the validation**

I can't say for sure what is causing your problem with the curly bracket, and it is probably located in another file than yours if the following code does not work, please upload your full project somewhere so i can investigate it further.
I rewrote your validation code and shortened it a little bit (since you weren't proud of it)

```
$('#contact_form').on('click', '#submit', function() {
    var validations = {
        first_name: new RegExp(/^[^\d]{3,}$/),
        last_name: new RegExp(/^[^\d]{3,}$/),
        phone: new RegExp(/^[\d]{10}$/),
        email: new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i)
    }

    $('input, textarea').removeClass('error');

    for (var key in validations)
        if (!validations[key].test(contactform[key].value))
            $(contactform[key]).addClass('error');

    if (!$('#contact_form .error').length)
        alert("Formularul este completat corect!");
});
```

Comment: Note that `first_name: new RegExp(/^[^\d]{3,}$/)`  = `first_name: /^[^\d]{3,}$/` and `[^\d]` = `\D`